# Accessing firewall configuration from container

Tags: symfony, security, config, firewall

If I have the following

```
security:
    firewalls:
        user:
            form_login:
                login_path: user_login
        admin:
            form_login:
                login_path: admin_login
```

Is there a way in symfony to access the current login_path option in any class?

Answer (score 1):

You could define both of them as parameters in your config and then do:

```
login_path: %user_login%
...
admin_path: %admin_login%
```

And do wherever you have access to the contaier

```
$container->getParameter('user_login');
...
$container->getParameter('admin_login');
```

Comment: But like this there is no way to get the "current" login_path, how should I know in the controller which parameter I should get user_login or admin_login?

Comment: You should define two different parameters, one for `user_login` and one for `admin_login`. Anyway, in you Controller, you should know where you are, I guess. How couldn't you?

Comment: That's true for a controller but not for other classes. Is there a way to get the current provider key?

Comment: Can you give us some explanations ? I fail to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am creating a new security listener factory which has 2 new options which are 'google_recaptcha_key' and 'always_show_captcha'.

Now these 2 options can be different per firewall, so I can have a different captcha for user/admin firewall.

Now I need to use these 2 options in a Manager class. This manager class needs to be aware of the current firewall and those 2 options.

For more info I have this github page https://github.com/syspay/login-recaptcha-bundle